# com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: web-services, rest, maven, jersey

I am getting the following exception when I try to hit a HelloWorld RESTful web service implemented using Jersey and maven on Apache Tomcat.

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/TestRest/rest/hello/abcd
```

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

I looked at various sources on internet, they say the exception occurs because of not having class in the package structure given in web.xml, but I made sure that they are all correct.

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Following is the code of pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>my.test.rest</groupId>
      <artifactId>TestRest</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>TestRest Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <repositories>
                <repository>
                <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
                <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
                <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>TestRest</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is the simple HelloWorldService.

```
package com.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String output = "Hello, " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

}
```

And finally, the web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I hope the directory structure of mine is correct too, please correct me if it isn't.

[image: Directory Structure]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have the HelloWorldService.java in the wrong source folder. It must be in src/main/java **not** in src/main/resources. It's a big big difference!

It means that your Java code has not been compiled and that's why you get the error. No class that can handle the request.

Take a look at the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, its a problem in Eclipse Indigo while developing RESTful web services in Java using Maven  because it doesn't create correct directory structure. So, deleting the given source directory and adding source as src/main/java as @maba rightly mentioned is the best workaround.
You may refer this for detailed explanation on developing RESTful web services in Java in Eclipse Indigo using Maven...

http://kausalmalladi.blogspot.in/2012/11/developing-restful-java-web-service-in.html